# Equal sizes of Pictures GridView in Android

Tags: android, image, gridview, pixel, image-size

I want to display 2 images in a Row in `GridView`.

I have tried to get the screen size in different ways. For example:

```
final int h = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;

and set size of the image..
convertView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(h, h));
```

But this is not sufficent. If screen is large, then 2 images look very small - like peanut, on a big screen.

Can anyone guide me that for example. Device's screen size is 4 inches in Portrait and I can create 2 images of almost 2 inches each.

[image]

here is my gridview xml file

```
  <GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:alwaysDrawnWithCache="true"
        android:clipChildren="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:scrollingCache="true"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
         >
    </GridView>
```

Comment: If a screen is large, then 2 images look very small? Shouldn't it rather be that if a screen is larger, then your images are also larger? And to be honest, I don't really understand what is your problem.

Comment: I have added more info in my problem. hope this time you will understand and ll try to help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add these attributes to your grid
android:columnWidth="200dp"
 android:stretchMode="columnWidth"

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to change the images size based on the screen size, if so you should take a look at the [supporting multiple screen sizes](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) tutorial. Android already offers that functionality.

Also if you're only displaying two images horizontally you could use a LinearLayout instead, using a GridView is overkill.

Comment: New i have added more information. Kindly help if you understand

Answer (score 0):

Just set the number of columns of the GridView in XML.

Answer (score 0):

To make equal sized images, make the `ImageView`  like this [SquaredImageView](https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/picasso-sample/src/main/java/com/example/picasso/SquaredImageView.java)

and if you want `Layout` to be of equal size then follow the same method describe on `onMeasure` of `SquaredImageView`